# WebGrid not shown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

My View consists of following code

```
@{ 
    List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
    list.Add("1001");   
    list.Add("1002");
    list.Add("1003");

    var g = new WebGrid(source:list);
    g.GetHtml();            
}
```

nothing is there other than this but the grid is not shown, i can see grid's html in `Immediate Window` and it is correct but the grid is not shown at all. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why?

Because you never outputted anything to the response:

```
@{ 
    List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
    list.Add("1001");   
    list.Add("1002");
    list.Add("1003");

    var g = new WebGrid(source:list);
}

@g.GetHtml();
```

or:

```
@{ 
    List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
    list.Add("1001");   
    list.Add("1002");
    list.Add("1003");

    var g = new WebGrid(source:list);
    @g.GetHtml();
}
```